# Symfony - Setting validation_groups on submit skips the validation_groups callback for the type

Tags: symfony, symfony-forms

In symfony I have a multi-stage form that embeds other forms. Some of these embedded forms have dynamic validation groups set via the `validation_groups` callback in the `configureOptions` (used to be setDefaultOptions) method for the type.

When the form is submitted via a submit that does not have its validation_groups option set, then these callbacks are run and the correct validation groups are used. But when I set the validation_groups option of a submit to a type that has this callback, then the callback is not run and the groups are not set as needed.

Are there any options that need to be set to have this working?

### Controller

```
$form = $this->createForm(new RegistrationType());
$form->add('Submit1', 'submit', array(
           'validation_groups' => array('Person'),
    ))
    ->add('Submit2', 'submit', array(
           'validation_groups' => array('Contact', 'Address'),
    ))
;

...
```

### Registration type

```
namespace AppBundle\Form;

use Symfony\Component\Form\AbstractType;
use Symfony\Component\Form\FormBuilderInterface;
use Symfony\Component\OptionsResolver\OptionsResolver;

class RegistrationType extends AbstractType
{
    /**
     * @param FormBuilderInterface $builder
     * @param array $options
     */
    public function buildForm(FormBuilderInterface $builder, array $options)
    {
        $builder
            ->add('person', new PersonType())
            ->add('maritalStatus', 'entity', array(
                  'class' => 'AppBundle:MaritalStatus',
                  'choice_label' => 'status',
              ))
            ->add('spouse', new SpouseType())
            ->add('homeAddress', new AddressType())
            ->add('postalAddress', new AddressType())
            ->add('contact', new ContactType())
        ;
    }

    /**
     * @param OptionsResolverInterface $resolver
     */
    public function configureOptions(OptionsResolver $resolver)
    {
        $resolver->setDefaults(array(
            'data_class' => 'AppBundle\Entity\Registration',
            'cascade_validation' => true,
        ));
    }

    /**
     * @return string
     */
    public function getName()
    {
        return 'appbundle_registration';
    }
}
```

### PersonType

```
namespace AppBundle\Form;

use Symfony\Component\Form\AbstractType;
use Symfony\Component\Form\FormBuilderInterface;
use Symfony\Component\Form\FormInterface;
use Symfony\Component\OptionsResolver\OptionsResolver;

class PersonType extends AbstractType
{
    /**
     * @param FormBuilderInterface $builder
     * @param array $options
     */
    public function buildForm(FormBuilderInterface $builder, array $options)
    {
        $builder
            ->add('title', 'text')
            ->add('name', 'text')
            ->add('surname', 'text')
            ->add('fullName', 'text', array('required' => false))
            ->add('southAfrican', 'checkbox', array(
                  'required' => false,
                  'data' => true,
              ))
            ->add('identification', 'text')
        ;
    }

    /**
     * @param OptionsResolverInterface $resolver
     */
    public function configureOptions(OptionsResolver $resolver)
    {
        $resolver->setDefaults(array(
            'data_class' => 'AppBundle\Entity\Person',

            // Setting some groups dynamically based on input data
            'validation_groups' => function (FormInterface $form) {
                $data = $form->getData();
                $groups = array('Person');

                // Add southAfrican validation group if is a southAfrican
                if ($data->isSouthAfrican() === true) {
                    $groups[] = 'southAfrican';
                }

                // Add Married validation group is this is spouse and Married is selected
                if ($form->getParent()->getConfig()->getName() === 'spouse') {
                    if ($form->getParent()->getParent()->getData()->getMaritalStatus()->getStatus() === 'Married') {
                        $groups[] = 'married';
                    } elseif (($key = array_search('southAfrican', $groups)) !== false) {
                        unset($groups[$key]);
                    }
                // If this is not spouse then this is applicant so add its validation group
                } else {
                    $groups[] = 'applicant';
                }

                return $groups;
            },
            'cascade_validation' => true,
        ));
    }

    /**
     * @return string
     */
    public function getName()
    {
        return 'appbundle_person';
    }
}
```

Comment: Did you experiment with the `Valid` constraint yet? http://symfony.com/doc/current/reference/constraints/Valid.html

Comment: @Debreczeni yes, but it is to cascade validation to embeds while i only want to validate the embed based on the submit pressed and have the embed's validation groups callback called

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Submit button validation groups have precedence over Type's validation groups. `Form::getClickedButton` returns a clicked button that is bound to a current form or its parents.

The case you described can be resolved by passing callbacks instead of plain groups to the submit buttons. E.g.:

```
$form->add('Submit1', 'submit', array(
       'validation_groups' => function (FormInterface $form) {
           if ($form->isRoot()) {
                return array('Person');
           } else {
                return ($form->getConfig()->getOptions('validation_groups'))();
           }
       },
))
```

Comment: Thanks @origaminal, I just made a slight change by exiting the function early if the clicked button (`getClickedButton()`) is not the  button I expected.

Comment: No problem. Just didn't understand fully where do you call `getClickedButton()`. In listener?

Comment: In the callback (like the one you have above) - `$form->getRoot()->getClickedButton()`

Comment: Maybe I misunderstood something but the `SubmittedButton` `validation_groups` are called only when the button is clicked.

Comment: Haha, I'm reading too fast (thought this was the form type), will try this as it will be easier.

Comment: This worked as is needed. Just two points: the callback will pass a parameter of `Symfony\Component\Form\Form` not `FormInterface`; the type's callback needs to be called using `call_user_func` (inclosing it in brackets does not work for me) and `$form` needs to be passed to it.